# Python: execute a function a random number of times per day

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, compare, epoch

I'd like to execute a function a random number of times each day between set periods. Here's what I have so far:

```
def get_epochtime(dt=datetime.now()):
    EPOCH = datetime(1970, 1, 1)
    return (dt - EPOCH).total_seconds()

def get_todays_run_schedule(runs_per_day, run_between):
    now = datetime.now()
    window_start = now.replace(hour=run_between[0])
    window_end   = now.replace(hour=run_between[1])
    the_schedule = [ get_epochtime(radar.random_datetime(start=window_start, stop=window_end)) for t in range(randint(runs_per_day[0], runs_per_day[1])) ]
    the_schedule.sort()
    print("Today I will run %s times" % len(the_schedule))
    for run_at in the_schedule:
        print("I will run at " + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", time.localtime(run_at)))
    return the_schedule

# we will run between 2 and 4 times per day between the hours of 10 AM and 5 PM.
schedule = get_todays_run_schedule((2, 4), (10, 17))

while(True):
    now = datetime.now()
    nowsecs = get_epochtime(now)
    if now.hour == 0 and now.minute == 0 and now.second == 0:
        schedule = get_todays_run_schedule()
    if nowsecs in schedule:
        execute_my_function
    sleep(1)
```

Basically the idea is that at midnight and at first run, we come up with a run schedule which is a list of epoch times, the length of which is between two supplied integers. Each second we check the time and if the current time is within the list of run times, we execute our function. Finally, we sleep until the next second.

However, it isn't working at all. I suspect this might be because my datetime objects somehow include microseconds which is throwing off the comparison, but it could be because of something I'm not understanding about the nature of date time comparisons in python.

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to use an `in` check like this for timestamps. The microseconds can be a problem, but even if you truncate both `now` and your set to integral seconds, there's nothing stopping your loop from running at 15:25:25.907 and 15:25:27.033 and completely missing a scheduled event at 15:25:26.

Comment: Also, as a side note, you don't need to convert your `datetime` objects to numbers with `get_epochtime`; you can directly compare them, do date arithmetic on them, etc.

Comment: Thank you @abarnert, I suspected as much. Can you give me more details on how to implement this though?

Comment: I've written an answer, but first—are you doing this as a learning exercise, or to accomplish some actual task? Because there are pre-existing (and nicely-tested, and flexible) libraries that take care of all this stuff for you.

Comment: Nope, this isn't a programming exercise, it's a real-world problem. I'd much rather use a library. But my google-foo wasn't up to the challenge @abarnert (Hence the use of Radar library etc.)

Comment: I've heard good things about [`schedule]`(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule/0.5.0) being really easy for simple tasks, but I've never used it myself.

Comment: Another option is to not do this in Python in the first place. If you can turn `execute_my_function` into a standalone script, you can replace `get_todays_run_schedule` with another script that creates entries in the user cron (if you're on Mac or Linux) or Scheduled Tasks (for Windows), and then schedule that second script itself to run every midnight.

Comment: I considered using schedule, but I wasn't sure if it was fit for this purpose -- great for well-scheduled events, but I wasn't able to see how I'd use it for randomly-occurring ones. I did consider using system cron, but i'm targetting docker as my execution environment and that looked like it was going to add another layer of complexity if I needed to talk to system cron instead of just using python's sleep() function...

Comment: As I said, I don't know schedule very well—but with the more complicated scheduler libraries, it's just a matter of inserting a one-shot task for each timestamp in the random list, so I can't imagine that a library designed to be simpler/"for humans" would make it harder…

Comment: Actually, it looks like `schedule` may be a bit _too_ simple here—there's a trivial one-liner to schedule a periodic task, but not to schedule a one-shot task. So maybe look at the more complicated libraries like `APScheduler` after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that microseconds will be a problem for you here—both the objects in your list and the `now` will have microseconds, and running a loop only about once/second, the chance of any of those `now`s exactly matching an event timestamp are pretty slim.

But even if you fix that by truncating both `now` and the values in the list to seconds, that still won't solve the problem, it'll just make it an intermittent problem that's harder to debug. Consider what happens if you have an event at 15:25:26, and you start the loop at 15:25:25.907. You truncate that to 15:25:25, look it up, it's not there. Then you sleep for about a second, and call `now()`, and you get, say, 15:25:27.033. You truncate that to 15:25:27, look it up, and it's not there either.

Since you've already sorted the list, you can do something a whole lot simpler, which I'll demonstrate below. But first: While we're at it, the whole point of `datetime` objects is that they can do time comparisons, arithmetic, etc. directly, so you don't need to convert everything to numbers with something like your `get_epochtime`.

```
yesterday = datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    if now.date() > yesterday:
        schedule = get_todays_run_schedule()
        yesterday = now.date()
    while schedule and now >= schedule[0]:
        del schedule[0]
        execute_my_function
    sleep(1)
```

(Obviously you'll also need to change `get_todays_run_schedule` to return a list of `datetime` objects instead of a list of floats to do it this way, but you should be able to figure that out.)

Also, notice that this way, we always know the time until the next event, so we don't need to loop around `sleep(1)` and keep waking the computer every second while it's on battery. You can just `sleep(schedule[0] - now)` when there is a next event, or sleep until midnight when there isn't. Or, maybe more simply, generate tomorrow's schedule when `schedule` goes empty, and then just sleep until its `schedule[0]`.

In fact, if you think about it, you should be able to figure how to turn this into a loop in this form:

```
while True:
    schedule = make_today_or_tomorrow_schedule()
    for event in schedule:
        while datetime.now() < event:
            sleep(event - datetime.now())
        execute_my_function
```

Comment: I love the brevity of the last example @abarnert